# OleDbDataAdapter exception in vb.net DataGridView using accdb (Access)

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, oledbdataadapter

Why it tells me "Update unable to find TableMapping['DiscTable'] or DataTable 'DiscTable'."
on this line:

da.Update(ds, "DiscTable")

I tried with da.Update(ds) and also crashes. The update in the table is successful anyway!?!? If I remove this its Ok!

```
Private Sub SelectBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SelectBtn.Click
    Dim ConnString As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim OleDBConn As New OleDbConnection()
    Dim OleDBCmd As New OleDbCommand()
    Dim OleDBdr As OleDbDataReader
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim IsChecked As Boolean = CBool(DiscDG.Rows(SelectedRowIndex).Cells(SelectedColIndex).Value)

    ConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=RegDB.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"

    SQLStr = "UPDATE DiscTable " +
             "SET LectionsTeacher='" + TeacherLblValue + "', LectionsYN=Yes " +
             "WHERE DiscName='" + SelectedRowFirstCell + "'"

    OleDBConn.ConnectionString = ConnString
    OleDBConn.Open()

    OleDBCmd.Connection = OleDBConn
    OleDBCmd.CommandText = SQLStr
    OleDBdr = OleDBCmd.ExecuteReader

    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(SQLStr, OleDBConn)
    da.Update(ds, "DiscTable")

    OleDBdr.Close()
    OleDBConn.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that since the dataset is empty there is not table called "DiscTable". I take it you have executed a "SELECT" query at some point which should give you a set of that you want to update. That dataset is the one you are supposed to do the update on.

What you are doing now is pointless, you might as well execute a "SELECT" query. This since you are trying to fill the empty data set with data rather than updating an existing one. Then as an added bonus you are filling ds which is a local object. When you reach End Sub that data set is gone. So you actually have no use of trying to update it at all.

Comment: I have the table DiscTable and its filled with data. I use a Select onFormLoad and fill the datagrid with it (with SELECT statement). Then I do something on the DataGrid (enter text check checkboxes..) and want to update the table.

Comment: But you are updating an empty Dataset. You are not updating the dataset you filled with the select statement. The object ds does not know about DiscTable since it is empty.